# Show certificate details?

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, ssl-certificate

When Safari sees an improper certificate, it offers the user a chance to cancel, accept it anyway, or show details about the certificate. I want to copy this behavior in my iOS app.

To be really clear, I am not interested in the **server** side of this, just the handling of the certificate details on the **client** side.

[image: Certificate Prompty]

I can get a prompt like this. I've written the code to handle the **Cancel** and **Continue** buttons as Safari does, but I don't know how to invoke the **Details** screen. It seems too complex to just code my own similar screen.

[image: Certificate Details]

Is this screen available in one of Apple's frameworks, or would I be stuck implementing this from scratch?